# Does using USB 2.0 or 3.0 cables affect charging speed with same adapter?

Tags: usb, charging

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3. If I charge my phone using the same adapter but with different cables, does that affect the charging speed with the USB 2.0 cable or 3.0 cable, supposing the 2.0 cable is of best quality, so both cables are good themselves?

Comment: You are wrong by 'am supposing the 2.0 cable is of best quality', because USB 3.0 is faster

Comment: i am not wrong by supposing the 2.0 cable is of best quality because sometime 3d party cables comes in bad quality which affects the charging it self. so that sentence serves to eleminate that claim as i am talking in a theoratical approach

Comment: Ok, so USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 dont have any charging speed differences

Answer (score 2):

USB 2.0 cables and USB 3.0 cables don't charge your device any faster because: USB 3.0 only increases the speed of copying files to your PC and back, but does not affect the charging speed

Comment: so it doesnt have any difference in capacity of charges carried?

Comment: No USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 cables are the exact same in charging speed (Unless one cable is copper wired and another is another metal, which would chang the power by around 0.00000000001 v.)

Answer (score 1):

To check the amount of current (in mAh) received by the mobile, use app called - [CurrentWidget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget).

Only High Quality Cables will give you high current from the adapter. For example, when your adapter has max output of 2A and using high quality USB 2.0, you will get around 1900mA which is almost equal to Battery Output. On the other hand, when the cable is bent (due to frequent usage), the current transferred via the cable is less.

Also, USB 2.0 and 3.0 cable does not result in fast charge. Rather, USB 2.0/3.0 port on PC provides high current output as well as data transfer rate. On PC, USB 3.0 gives you around 2000mAh current with good cable, whereas 2.0 gives approximately 500mAh.

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any difference , if you are charging from a wall adapter (assuming both cables are fine as mentioned)

But, if you are using your laptop, things change.  USB 3.0 port compared to a USB 2.0 port, the [former](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) has a maximum rated capacity of 900mA, whereas [latter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) has a rating of 500 mA (80 % faster). In this situation

- USB cable 3 connected to laptop USB port 3.0 (your phone has USB 3 port ) will charge faster at 900 mA
- USB cable 2 connected to laptop USB port 3.0 and your phone , which has USB 3 port will charge  at 500 mA (since USB 3.0 port  is backward compatible and can accept a USB 2 connection)
- USB cable 2 or 3 connected to laptop USB port 2.0 and your phone , which has USB 3 port will charge  at 500 mA

Also see related question from SE superuser [Will a mobile phone charge faster if plugged into a USB 3.0 port](https://superuser.com/q/749192)

**Note:** Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (OP's) phone, is the first phone to have USB 3.0 port, subsequently discontinued in later models of Note series